# how can I pass an array with an offset in F#?

Tags: f#

I am using TA-Lib, which performs math functions on arrays. The nuget package is 'Cryptowatcher.TA-LIb-Core'

One of the functions I am using is an EMA. Without going into the details, it takes an array of floats and an int parameter and will return an array of floats.

The output array is shorting than the input array; it has (parameter - 1) less values.

So, if I pass an array of 20 floats and a parameter of 5, I get 16 floats back.

For some reason, my IDE doesn't want to dive into the lib I'm using so here's a screenshot of the function type:

[image]

an example of usage is:

```
    let data = [| ...... |]
    let period = 10

    let mutable outStartIndex = 0
    let mutable outNbElement = 0

    let allocationSize = data.Length - period - 1
    let mutable emaData : float array = Array.zeroCreate allocationSize

    let retCode = Core.Ema(0, data.Length, data, period, &outStartIndex, &outNbElement, emaData)
```

What I would like to do is create an output array that has the same size as the input and have the main function start filling the data from (period-1) to the end.

right now I have:

```
    input:  IIIIIIIIII
    output: OOOOOOOO
```

but what I want is:

```
    input:  IIIIIIIIII
    output: --OOOOOOOO
```

so, instead of passing 'emaData' in the function, I would really need to pass '&emaData[period-1]' to it but I am not sure how to make that happen in F#.

since speed is quite important, I don't want to build the output and then concatenate it with another array because it will cause unnecessary copies.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a native pointer to an index within an array using the `&&` operator, as in the following example:

```ml
open FSharp.NativeInterop

let mutate (p: nativeptr<int>) =
    NativePtr.set p 2 4


let mutable x = [| 0; 1; 2; 3 |]

mutate &&x.[1]
```

This changes the last element of the array to 4, resulting in the following value for `x`:

```ml
int [] = [|0; 1; 2; 4|]
```

In your example, I think you would do: `&&emaData.[period-1]`

Comment: I have to pull this as an answer because, despite teaching me something new, it doesn't solve the problem mentioned above: ta-lib will not let me pass something in the form of &&x.[y]